# Subscription in subscription better writing in angular2+ with switchMap

Tags: angular, rxjs

Can someone please help me write this code better. I can't seem to understand switchMap, mergeMap and how to get rid of subscription in subscription.

```
this.service
  .service1('something')
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
  .subscribe(
    (s1result) => {
      if (s1result.IsOK) {
        this.service
          .service2()
          .pipe(take(1))
          .subscribe((s2result) => {
            'IS OK MESSAGE';
          });
      } else {
        'NOT OK MESSAGE';
      }
    },
    () => {}
  );
```

Comment: If you are looking to learn more about Observables, you could check out this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knUgpZrxUII And for more on higher order mapping operators (such as switchMap), this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldRdjc-60PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `switchMap` like this:

```js
this.service
  .service1('something')
  .pipe(
       takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
       switchMap((s1result)=> {
         if (s1result.IsOK) {
           return this.service
            .service2()
            .pipe(take(1));
        } else {
          return of(EMPTY);
        }
       })
  )
  .subscribe(
    (s2result) => {
      s2result ? 'IS OK MESSAGE' : 'NOT OK MESSAGE';
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful. I think i understood how to use it now. I will look more on documentation.

Comment: You can use the same method as above by @eko and use ````mergeMap```` instead of ````switchMap```` too.  Thats another way of doing the same thing.